# relationship database diferend id

Tags: mysql

I am making a simple mysql/php storage program for me and I stuck in a place and I don`t know exactly how to do it:/

I have a  relationship database and there I have 3 tables ( there are more but now the 3 are important ) so table 1 has a relationship with table 2 and table 2 with table 3

1--->2---->3 let call them Shop=1 customers=2 repairs=3
now if I have 3 repair shops and in every shop there are customers witch have stuff to repair. I want to check in witch shop what is for repair and I am doing that fine BUT!! the problem is with the ID 
for example when I write shop1 with customer:tom has to repair Laptop lenovo. I'll get ID 1 for that customer and shop2 with customer: john hast to repair TV then i get id 2 for that customer.
in short I want for each  customer witch is in another repair service the ID for them to begin from Zero like I have 3 separate tables for each service.
i hope you get what I want :/

like :

```
 SERVICE 1         service 2              service 3
 id 1 customer 1   id=1 customer2        id=1 customer 3
```

Now i have it like this
service 1            service 2         service 3
id=1 customer 1      id=2 customer2    id=3 customer 3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7SdO.png)
hope u get the idea ; ) sorry for my bad language

Comment: What is your question? Note that "how can I do this?" is not a question appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 0):

in short i want every etry to be with a diferent iD starting form 0 depending on witch shop the customer is written to  :/ i guess its something wrong with the  relationship... how is it correct to do it?

Comment: Don't use an answer to write explanations. you can edit your question, or comment on it.